# boost propagation speed

Tags: transactions, transaction-propagation

Is there a way to boost propagation?
E.g if someone sent me an amount, he says that he sees the txid in blockchain because he is connected to faster nodes, and I search this txid and I see it doesn't exist, because I'm connected to slower nodes.
Is there a way that I will be connected to faster nodes? So I won't need to wait a few seconds/minutes to receive the data because I have slower nodes.

Comment: Are you running your own node? Or looking up the transaction using a blockchain explorer service? Transactions will propagate through the network very quickly, this "I'm connected to fast nodes, you're connected to slow nodes" explanation sounds like something a scammer might tell you.

Comment: @chytrik I'm running my own node, I'm asking if a case like I wrote may happen that the sender sees and the receiver doesn't see yet.